# PHP exec() Permission Issue: Unable to Use Conda

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to use the exec() function in PHP to execute a shell script, implementing TensorFlow image processing on a web page after the user uploads an image. This shell script is responsible for activating a Conda environment and running a Python file containing the TensorFlow image processing code. However, when I attempt to execute the Conda command, I encounter the following error message: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.config/conda/.condarc'. I suspect this is due to PHP's user permissions and environment settings on the web terminal not allowing me to use Conda, but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. I can't even find the path '/root/.config/conda/.condarc'. How can I handle this problem to successfully execute the TensorFlow image processing program? Thank you!

upload.php

```
<?php
$targetDir = "/home/vto/HumanParse/datasets/images/"; // Specify the location
if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
    mkdir($targetDir, 0777, true); // Create directories recursively if necessary
}
$targetFile = $targetDir . basename(@$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
print_r($_FILES); // Output the contents of the $_FILES array to check if the file upload information is correctly passed

// Check if the file already exists
if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
    echo "Sorry, the file already exists.\n";
    //exit;
}
echo "Target file path: " . $targetFile . "\n";
// Upload file
if (move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $targetFile)) {
    echo "File uploaded successfully.\n";
    $output = null;
    $retval = null;
    exec('bash script.sh', $output, $retval);
} else {
    echo "Error uploading file.\n";
}
?>
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Specify the path to the log file
LOG_FILE="/home/vto/logfile.log"

# Redirect standard output and standard error to the log file
exec > >(tee -a "$LOG_FILE") 2>&1

# Change directory
cd '/home/vto/HumanParse'

# Activate the virtual environment
source /home/vto/miniconda3/bin/activate tf

# Display virtual environment information to the log file
conda info >> "$LOG_FILE"

# Execute the Python script
python inference_pgn.py
```

error report

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/vto/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/vto/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 97, in main_sourced
        context.__init__()
      File "/home/vto/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 472, in __init__
        self._set_search_path(
      File "/home/vto/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 1416, in _set_search_path
        self._search_path = IndexedSet(self._expand_search_path(search_path, **kwargs))
      File "/home/vto/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boltons/setutils.py", line 125, in __init__
        self.update(other)
      File "/home/vto/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boltons/setutils.py", line 355, in update
        for o in other:
      File "/home/vto/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 1389, in _expand_search_path
        if path.is_file() and (
      File "/home/vto/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1439, in is_file
        return S_ISREG(self.stat().st_mode)
      File "/home/vto/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1198, in stat
        return self._accessor.stat(self)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.config/conda/.condarc'

`$ /home/vto/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.posix activate tf`
```

In my web code, I used the `whoami` command to check the user, and it returned "daemon". Then, I tried changing the ownership of miniconda/bin to daemon using `chown`, but I still encountered permission issues. I also attempted `chmod 777 miniconda/bin`, but neither of these methods worked.

I even tried accessing ~/.bashrc using `sudo -u daemon nano ~/.bashrc` on the local terminal to add Miniconda's environment variables as the daemon user, but it failed as well.

I'm also try to added www-data user to sudoers file

I hope to be able to execute commands on my web server just like I can on my local terminal.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. It will e.g. answer whether this is specific to conda at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the conda configuration file `/root/.config/conda/.condarc`, try adding permissions there.

If the problem persist, you can try executing php as root or using sudo.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I couldn't find the path /root/.config/conda/.condarc, so I couldn't change its permissions. I tried running the command with sudo, but it shows "sudo: conda: command not found."